# Is this a typo in my math book?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am doing homework which is submitted online. I came across a question asking if two functions are equal. $f(x)=3x+4$ and $g(x)=14+(8/x)+b(x-4)$. I set the two equations together and got 7 for an answer but the book says the answer is $\frac {7}{3}$.

Here is an image of the solution in the book:
[image]

Comment: Perhaps you should edit your query here to state the **question** that was asked clearly. The two functions ae _not_ equal as functions. The solution seems to suggest that what was asked is something like "Find all values of $b$ suc that $f(-3) = g(-3)$ and $f(4) = g(4)$", that is the functions have equal value for two specific values of $x$. This is quite different from saying that the functions are equal.

Answer (score 5):

If you set $f(-3) = g(-3)$, you end up with:

$$-5 = 14 -(8/3) -7b$$

If you multiply by 3 to remove fractions, you are left with

$$-15 = 42 - 8 -21b$$

Collecting like terms, we are left with

$$21b = 49$$

reducing yields: $$b = 7/3$$

Can you find your error?

Answer (score 4):

The book is correct. Setting $f(-3)=g(-3)$ gives us

$-5=14-\frac{8}{3}-7b \Rightarrow -19=-\frac{8}{3}-7b \Rightarrow 49=21b \Rightarrow b=\frac{7}{3}$.

Answer (score 2):

Well, at least to your specific question "Is this a typo?", the answer is "No."  You are making an arithmetic error somewhere, because: $$\frac{1}{7}\bigg(\frac{34}{3} + \frac{15}{3}\bigg) = \frac{1}{7}\frac{49}{3} = \frac{7}{3}.$$

Answer (score 1):

> $$ -5 = \left(\frac{34}{3}\right) - 7B$$

Multiply both sides by 3:

$$-15= 3\cdot\left(\frac{34}{3}\right) - 3\cdot(7B)$$

that is:

$$-15 = 34 - 21B$$

so

$$-15-34 = -21B$$

$$B=\frac{49}{21}=\frac{7}{3}$$

The book is correct on this one.

Comment: @Joe, appreciate the Tex work.

Comment: No problem - was just minor while I was reading this problem. :)